# Bound on hypergeometric sum ${}_2F_1(-n,-n;1,4)$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in the values ${}_2F_1(-n,-n;1;4)$ of hypergeometric functions and in particular in the scaling in $n$.
Numerical experiments suggest that this can be bounded by $9^n$. I also have reason to believe that this scaling is almost tight.

From the definition of ${}_2F_1$ it can be shown that
\begin{equation}
{}_2F_1(-n,-n;1;4)=\sum_{j=0}^n {n\choose j}^2 4^j.
\end{equation}

More generally, is there a strategy to find similar bounds for values other that $4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sum can be written in terms of the Legendre polynomials as follows
$$
3^n P_n \!\left( {\tfrac{5}{3}} \right).
$$
The known asymptotics of the Legendre polynomials for large $n$ implies
$$
3^n P_n \!\left( {\tfrac{5}{3}} \right) \sim \frac{3}{{2\sqrt {2\pi n} }}9^n .
$$
The same argument works with values other than $4$. Numerical computation suggests that the RHS is actually an upper bound.